# I'm looking at adopting a cat that had basal cell carcinoma

Tags: cats, health, skin-condition, cancer

I would like to adopt a cat with basal cell carcinoma.  The shelter's vet removed the tumor and had it tested, it was benign.  As far as they know the cat is cancer-free now, am I assuming more risk by adopting this cat?  Is this cat more likely to have cancer than any other cat?

Comment: I think it would be a great idea to talk to your local vet about this. Not only for a professional opinion but also to give you a better idea about the potential medical costs (even if there is no risk of cancer). All of which would better ease your mind and help you decide if this is the right decision for you and the cat.

Comment: If you're adopting from a shelter, they may offer a few months' pet insurance. By renewing the policy as needed, you can minimise your medical costs.

Comment: The info you provided is not adequate for a thorough answer. I would take all the cats records and consult a feline oncologist. Find one in your area and call for an appointment for a consultation to be better informed about the risks. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I have experience with Basal Cell Carcinoma in a human (me, 73M).

BCC is non-metastasizing (won't spread), but will grow back if tumor removal is incomplete.

Having a BCC doesn't (I've been told)    influence other cancer possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Late to discussion here – but a basal cell carcinoma, is by definition malignant (being a [carcinoma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carcinoma)). However, the vast majority of basal cell tumors are not carcinomas and are benign (basal cell epithelioma). Complete excision performed by the vet is good prognostically in either case.

The histopathology report would need to be seen to give any more specifics on this particular case.

If it is a basal cell carcinoma (malignant), the good news is that these are a low-grade malignancy. It is possible, but rare, for these to metastasize (spread). Whether basal cell carcinoma or benign basal cell tumor, the treatment of choice is surgical excision. Wide surgical margins are typically recommended, and in many cases curative, though local recurrence is possible. (Source [VIN](https://www.vin.com), Basal Cell Tumor)